# How to import mysql data into postgresql in Heroku?(Django project)

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql, heroku

Recently I need to import **mysql** data into **postgres** database in **Heroku**. Actcually it includes several steps:

1. convert mysql data to postgresql
2. import postgresql data to Heroku

After referring plenty of materials and testing several tools in github, finally I succeed. Here I want to share some of my experience and references.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I list some tools for converting mysql database format into postgresql format.

1. [mysql-postgresql-converter](https://github.com/lanyrd/mysql-postgresql-converter)
   : I finally use this tool and succeed. Dump MySQL database in PostgreSQL-compatible format

> mysqldump -u username -p --compatible=postgresql databasename > outputfile.sql

then use the converter to transfer data into `*.psql` file. then load new dump into a fresh PostgreSQL database.

2. [mysql2postgres](https://github.com/maxlapshin/mysql2postgres/tree/fde9043b97bd4c9b0f67795827fd5687fb1462e9) : It is a tool which is introduced in Heroku Dev Center. Just refer here [Migrating from MySQL to Postgres on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-mysql#migrate-to-heroku-postgres). it is based on Ruby. However, as for me, I found some [issues](https://github.com/maxlapshin/mysql2postgres/issues/95) after I finish installation and cannot solve it.

> You have already activated test-unit 2.5.5, but your Gemfile requires test-unit 3.2.3. #95

3. [py-mysql2pgsql](https://github.com/philipsoutham/py-mysql2pgsql): Similar process with mysql2postgres above by editing a `*.yml` file for configuration. There is a nice reference table in README file called **Data Type Conversion Legend**, which compares different data type between MySQL and PostgreSQL. You can manually modify the data type.

** [This website](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Converting_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL) lists some other converting methods.

Some basic operations in PostgreSQL:

```
$sudo su - postgres
$createtedb testdb
$psql testdb
=# create user username password ' password ';
-- To change a password:
=# alter role username password ' password ';
=# create database databasename with encoding 'utf8';
```

How to list all database in postgres: [PostgreSQL - SELECT Database](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_select_database.htm)

```
postgres-# \l
                         List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+---------+-------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 testdb    | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
(4 rows)

postgres-#
```

Now type the below command to connect/select a desired database, here we will connect to the testdb database:

```
postgres=# \c testdb;
psql (9.2.4)
Type "help" for help.
You are now connected to database "testdb" as user "postgres".
testdb=#
```

After you create your database, import the converted tables into psql. Kindly note that a database should be created before importing data.

```
$psql -h server -d databasename -U username -f data.sql
```

(sometimes a `sudo -u postgres` should be added before psql)

How to generate dump of psql using pg_dump: [creating dump file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html)

```
$sudo -u postgres pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U postgres databasename > mydb.dump
```

The next step, how to import data into Heroku Postgres?
After previous steps, you may have import data into your local PostgresSQL or generate a pg_dump file. Here two methods will be introduced to transfer data to remote Heroku Postgres.

1. use pg_dump file.[reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import)
   Use the raw file URL in the `pg:backups restore` command:

   ```
   $ heroku pg:backups:restore 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/me/items/3H0q/mydb.dump' DATABASE_URL
   ```

In this case, you should firstly upload the dump file to somewhere with an HTTP-accessible URL. The dev center in Heroku [recommend using Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).
The `DATABASE_URL` represents the `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR_URL` of the database you wish to restore to. For example, my database url is postgresql-globular-XXXXX.

2. use [pg:push](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push-and-pg-pull) 
   `pg:push` will push data from your local psql database into remote Heroku Postgres database. The command looks like this:

   ```
   $heroku pg:push mylocaldb DATABASE_URL --app sushi
   ```

This command will take the local database "mylocaldb" and push it to the database at `DATABASE_URL` on the app "sushi". Kindly note that the remote database must be empty before performing `pg:push` in order to prevent accidental data overwrites and loss.
Actually I use this `pg:push` method and succeed finally.

More information about Heroku Postgres can be found in [official document of Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup).

**others:

1. [Viewing logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#view-logs) of your web application in Heroku: `heroku logs --tail`
2. [How to deploy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python) Python and Django Apps on Heroku?
3. How to write the Procfile of Django Apps? 
   A common Procfile of Django projects will look like this:

   ```
   web: gunicorn yourprojectname.wsgi --log-file -
   ```

Here web is a single process type. What we need to modify is `yourprojectname.wsgi`. Just replace your project name in the prefix.

4. How to add Gunicorn to your application?

   ```
   $ pip install gunicorn
   $ pip freeze > requirements.txt
   ```
5. How to run command line in remote Heroku server?
   You can execute the `bash` command in Heroku.

   ```
   $heroku run bash
   Running bash attached to terminal... up, run.1
   ~ $ ls
   ```

Then you can do some command such `ls`, `cd` just like in your local bash.

Also, you can use commands in this pattern to execute `manage.py` in remote Heroku:`heroku run python manage.py runserver`